# Can Charles Proxy capture HTTPs traffic from Android official emulators?

Tags: proxy, android-emulator, charles-proxy

I followed the Charles documentation

> Android emulator In the Android emulator run configuration add an
>   Additional Emulator Command Line Option:
>   -http-proxy http://LOCAL_IP:8888
>
> Where LOCAL_IP is the IP address of your computer, not 127.0.0.1 as
>   that is the IP address of the emulated phone.

Also I installed the Charles certificate on the emulator. But still it doesn't work.

Charles seems to have been able to capture HTTP traffic from it but not HTTPs.

Comment: So are you not able to see the logs for https in Charles side pane ?